# How Spring instantiate this class and its dependancy

Tags: spring

Not sure this is a spring related or not:

I have a bean class like this

```
class BeanClass {
    private ServiceA serviceA;
    private ServiceB serviceB;

    public BeanClass() {}

    public void setServiceA(ServiceA serviceA) {
        this.serviceA = serviceA;
    }

    public void setServiceB(ServiceB serviceB) {
        this.serviceB = serviceB;
    }

    public void callService() {
        serviceA.a();
        serviceB.b();
    }
}
```

and its configuration:

```
<bean id="beanClass" class="BeanClass">
    <property name="serviceA" ref="serviceA"/>
    <property name="serviceB" ref="serviceB"/>
</bean>
```

but I instantiate the bean with new keyword in a controller class:

```
class ControllerClass {
    public void someMethod() {
        BeanClass beanClass = new BeanClass();
        beanClass.callService();
    }
}
```

my problem is how ServiceA and ServiceB got instantiated properly? since I use new to got a class object, and never set its field member.

Answer (score 1):

You don't want to do:

```
BeanClass beanClass = new BeanClass();
```

This in a nutshell is the whole point of Spring's IOC container.  You should let the IOC container give you a reference to your  BeanClass

```
@Autowired
BeanClass myBeanClass;
```

*This isn't entirely complete as you'll need a bit of extra wiring for your controller.

Comment: Thanks! I know this is not a good practice. I just want to make sure how Spring instantiate its field member? e.g. ServiceA, ServiceB.

Comment: It will create instances for the 2 properties you defined, and then call you setters.

Comment: thank you! You mean Spring will use bean definition to instantiate BeanClass when it see new BeanClass(), even I call it from a normal method and assign it to a local variable.